# Requiring unknown module "699"

Tags: javascript, react-native, module, frontend

I've tried importing my Settings screen to my drawer config in order to import both of them on app.js but I get an error requiring a certain module "699". Can anyone help please?

```
import React from 'react';
import { Platform, Dimensions} from 'react-native';
import { createDrawerNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';

import SettingScreen from '../Menu/SettingScreen'

const WIDTH = Dimensions.get('window').width;

const DrawerConfig = {
    drawerWidth: WIDTH*0.83,
}

const DrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator(
    {
    Settings: {
       screen: SettingScreen
    },
},
DrawerConfig
);

export default createAppContainer(DrawerNavigator);
```

Comment: Try checking your debugger console.

Answer (score 5):

This type of error is often a problem regarding Metro Bundler. To solve this issue, close metro bundler and re-run your application.

---

If that doesn't work, clear the Metro Bundler cache as mentioned [here](https://gist.github.com/jarretmoses/c2e4786fd342b3444f3bc6beff32098d).
Run these commands to clear metro bundler cache but do this at ***YOUR*** own risk.

```
RN < 0.50 - watchman watch-del-all && rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-* && rm -rf node_modules/ && npm cache clean && npm install && npm start -- --reset-cache
RN >= 0.50 -  watchman watch-del-all && rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-native-packager-cache-* && rm -rf $TMPDIR/metro-bundler-cache-* && rm -rf node_modules/ && npm cache clean && npm install && npm start -- --reset-cache

npm >= 5 - watchman watch-del-all && rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-* && rm -rf node_modules/ && npm cache verify && npm install && npm start -- --reset-cache

Windows - del %appdata%\Temp\react-native-* & cd android & gradlew clean & cd .. & del node_modules/ & npm cache clean --force & npm install & npm start -- --reset-cache
```

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen if an import path either has a wrong relative path or you have not installed the NPM module

Comment: So how do I know whether I have to clear the Metro Bundler or if it's related to a wrong relative path or an uninstalled npm module. Because I've been searching for the module concerned but no result is being shown. Maybe this new error would help, I have another error this time for module 700 also. Related to Ionicons installation, I have replicated the basic installations but still an error. It seems that I will have to clear the Metro bundler most probably but what are the risks related to it exactly?

Comment: Just remove your node_modules, run "npm install" and then start your bundler with "npm start -- --reset-cache". There should be no risks as long as you have not edited files in node_modules. If that does not work, start by commenting out the imports and the usages until the error goes away, then you know what import is wrong.